# Use google search in my site

Tags: php

I want to use Google search.But the search results are only from my site, not from any other site. The searched word or phrase should be highlighted.

Pls help me...

Comment: This is not a question, but asking someone to make it. What about reading [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) before asking such questions?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow pal, check [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to ask better questions, good luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The link you are looking for is

> [Google Site Search](http://www.google.com/sitesearch/)

remember, always do a quick Google before asking a question on SO. When you type the title of your question into Google Search, Site Search is the #2 result.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [**Google Custom Search**](http://www.google.com/cse/).